# Different Forms of Geometric Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, itos-lemma

If the stock price S follows the geometric brownian motion:
$$dS=\mu Sdt+\sigma Sdz$$
$$\frac{dS}S=\mu dt+\sigma dz$$

Where $dz=\epsilon\sqrt{dt}$ is a wiener process.

Integrating this to get $S_T$ as a function of $S_0$

$$\int^T_0\frac{1}Sds=\int^T_0\mu dt +\int^T_0\sigma dz$$ $$=ln(S_T/S_0)=\mu(T-0)+\sigma (z_T-z_0)$$

$$S_T=S_0e^{\mu T+\sigma (z_T-z_0)}$$
Why do others allow $(z_T-z_0)$ to be a standard Wiener process?

And why is this not the same as:
$$S_T =S_0 e^{(\mu -0.5\sigma^2)T+\sigma \epsilon \sqrt{T}}$$

And what is the difference between the above version, and this version:
$$S_T =S_0+dS=S_0+\mu S_0 T+\sigma S_0 \epsilon \sqrt{T}$$?

Answer (score 2):

Your integration of 1/S dS is incorrect for a stochastic process. You must use stochastic calculus. That would give you the adjustment term, somewhat like a convexity adjustment.